# Can't find the leak, on my fragment android code

Tags: android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-widget, commonsware

I have a TabLayout, under each tab there is a Fragment (I'm using ArrayPagerAdapter). I've noticed that when I switch many times from a tab to another, my memory usage increase a lot. From my heap snapshot, I can see there are a lot of AutoCompleteTextView instances.

[image: Android's studio memory tool]

So I am convinced that the problem could be here:

```java
public class MyFragment  {
...
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    final MultiAutoCompleteTextView eInput = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextInput);
    EditorListener mEditorListener = new EditorListener();
    eInput.setOnEditorActionListener(mEditorListener);
    eInput.addTextChangedListener(new WhitespaceWatcher());
    eInput.setAdapter(mDictionaryAdapter);
    eInput.setTokenizer(new SpaceTokenizer());
    ...
  }
...
  class EditorListener implements TextView.OnEditorActionListener
  {
  @Override
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    ...
    MultiAutoCompleteTextView input = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) textView.findViewById(R.id.TextInput);
    ...
  }
}
...
}
```

[image: Android Studio's memory tool Reference tree]

But I can't understand where exactly the problem is.

Comment: Well, there will be one `AutoCompleteTextView` widget per fragment that you have loaded. `ArrayPagerAdapter` works like `FragmentPagerAdapter`, in that all pages are kept in memory.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. My problem is that - from what I can see under Instances on Android Studio - everytime I switch a tab, a new instance of AutoCompleteTextView gets here. So if I have 4 tabs and I switch any of the tabs 4 times, I  get 16 instances of AutoCompleteTextView. Any idea of the reason? Thanks.

Comment: You would need to track down where you are creating these instances. For example, is `onCreateView()` being called 4 times or 16 times? If the latter, track down the places where you are creating instances of the fragment, and see if they are called 4 times or 16 times. It's certainly possible there is a bug in `ArrayPagerAdapter` -- for example, I have never used it with `appcompat-v7`, and for all I know those two will interact poorly for some unexpected reason.

Comment: onCreateView() is called every time I switch to the tab where the Fragment is contained, or when I switch to one tab near it (at distance == 1). Instances of the fragment are only 4, as they should.

Comment: OK, that's actually expected behavior -- leastways, `FragmentPagerAdapter` does the same thing. This suggests that `ArrayPagerAdapter` is not at fault, which is a relief. The references shown in the reference tree in theory can help you figure out what's holding onto the `AutoCompleteTextView`, though I find them difficult to use. You might try using [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary), as it tends to provide more focused details of what is the likely source of the leak.

Comment: Where should I place the watch() call for AutoCompleteTextView, with LeakCanary? They have one example with a Fragment leak and they place it inside onDestroy().

Comment: Well, if `onCreateView()` is called every time, then I'd try `onDestroyView()` for the `watch()` call. If you determine that `onDestroyView()` is not being called, that's probably another clue as to the source of the original problem.

Comment: onDestroyView() is fired, but LeakCanary isn't reporting anything.

Comment: :: shrug :: Well, other than poking through the heap dump reference tree, I have no other suggestions for you -- sorry!

Comment: After doing some try, I've found that the problem is on eInput.setAdapter(mDictionaryAdapter). Commenting it or setting mDictionaryAdapter = null inside onDestroyView solves the problem.  mDictionaryAdapter is defined as simple as new MyFragment.OutputArrayAdapter(R.layout.listview, R.id.Message, mChannel.getMessages()); but I can't still understand why it is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note to others: the poster and I had an off-SO discussion about this issue, and the poster created [this sample app](https://github.com/MyWay/AndroidLeakExample) that was able to reproduce the problem.

---

After some struggling, I was able to get [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to work. It required `1.4-beta1` versus the shipping `1.3.1`. All I needed to do was add the dependencies and set up an `Application` subclass per the `LeakCanary` docs. Then, launch the app and press BACK once the activity appears.

You get:

[image: LeakCanary Output]

Whether this is a framework bug or something introduced by `appcompat-v7` and its specific subclass of `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`, I can't say at present. However, it is definitely not a bug in your code.

Clearing the adapter from the `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` (`setAdapter(null)`) in `onDestroyView()` of the fragment should prevent it from leaking the activity, but the widget itself will still leak. A quick scan of the relevant code does not give me much hope that the leak itself can be fixed without modifications to either the framework (for `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`) or `appcompat-v7` (for its subclass).

Comment: The problem is not limited to `appcompat-v7`, or even `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`. The problem is exhibited with `AutoCompleteTextView` using native activities and fragments. I filed [a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200423), using a revised version of your sample app that eliminates a lot of the template-generated cruft (to ensure that the cruft wasn't contributing to the problem).

Comment: Nice job! Thanks for helping me to understand the problem.